# Truncated gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ a random variable with density $f_X(x)\propto \frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},x\in [-1,1]$, and let $Y|X=x \sim N(x,1)$. Find the value of $c$.

---

I'm really struggling the notation of proportionality: I don't understand how to approach the problem. Usually, when I have a random vector and I have to find the value of a constant I apply the standardisation condition $ 1=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy$, but in this case I get confused by the symbol $\propto$. Clearly I have to apply the definition $f_{Y|X}(x|y):=\frac{f_{XY}(x.y)}{f_X(x)}\Rightarrow f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(x|y)$. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we understand $x \propto y$ as $y=kx$, then, sure, you easily solve your question.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of $Y$ to this question.

Comment: @YJT This is the same text of the book.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks for your answer. I wrote $f_{Y|X}(x|y)=\frac{1}{(1)\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-x)^2}{2(1)^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Thus $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{c}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\rightarrow 1=\int_{1}^{-1}[\int_{x}^{1}\frac{c}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dy]dx$. Is it correct?

Comment: Something bad with your formatting ..

Comment: @zkutch I edited. Standardisation condition is $1=\int_{-1}^{+\infty}[\int_{x}^{1}f_{XY}(x,y)dy]dx=…=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-\int_{-\infty}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx-\int_{-1}^{+\infty}xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}]=\frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}[-1-e^{-\frac{1}{2}}]$. Right?

Comment: In your first sentence, what is the range on $x$?  I think you have a typo; at any rate I don't understand what  "$x\in1 , 1$ and let..." means.

Comment: What I meant - X is well defined without $Y$. So from $\int f(x)dx=1$ you should find $c$. Why does $Y$ matter?

Comment: @kimchilover Right, we have $x\in [-1,1$.

Comment: @YJT So why writing $Y|X=x$?

Comment: No clue. Maybe for a follow-up question?

Comment: @YJT So $1=\int_{-1}^{+\infty}\frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$?

Comment: According to your domain in the question, it seems like $\int_{-1}^1$, no?

Comment: @YJT So… I apologize for that but $[-1,1)$ (that is a range without closing bracket) can't be interpreted like $[-1,+\infty)$?

Comment: No. It doesn't matter if it's $1]$ or $1)$ and definitely not $\infty$. I agree with @tommik 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confuse with your text

> Let $X$ a random variable with density $f_X(x)\propto \frac{c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}},x\in [-1,1]$, and let $Y|X=x \sim N(x,1)$. Find the value of $c$.

If the marginal X density is truncated in $x \in[-1;1]$ the constant can be easily found by integrating the density  all over its domain

$$c\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=1$$

$$c[\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)]=1$$

$$c=\frac{1}{[\Phi(1)-\Phi(-1)]}=\frac{1}{[2\Phi(1)-1]}\approx 1,46479477349154$$

I do not understand why the text gives you also the conditional $(Y|X)$ density...perhaps is for a further question?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I'm sorry if I answer you only now. Well, the following questions are: 2) Find $\mathbb{E}(x)$ and $Var(x)$. 3) Find the density of $Y$. 4) Calculate $Cov(X,Y)$.

Comment: For 2) I wrote $\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{-1}^{1}x \frac{1,4648}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=...=0$ and (although I couldn't calculate it) I think that $Var(X)=1$. It's for point 3) that we have to use the conditional density… $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)\cdot f_{Y|X}(x|y)=\frac{1,4648}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\Rightarrow f_Y(y)=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1,4648}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$.

Answer (score 0):

@tommik Always for completeness:

2. $\mathbb{E}(X)=1, Var(X)=1\Rightarrow X\sim  N(0,1)$;
3. $f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Rightarrow Y\sim N(x,1)$;
4. $Cov(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}xyf_{XY}(x,y)dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}xf_X(x)dx[\int_{\mathbb{R}}yf_{Y|X}(x|y)dy]dx=\mathbb{E}[x\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[XX]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]=1$

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a truncated standard gaussian in $[-1;1]$ so its mean is 0. With simple calculations (integration by parts) you get $E[X^2]\approx 0,29=cov (X,Y)$

Y density is not easy to be calculated